# Issue with `this` using mongoose methods

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm running into an issue right now.
While I use the keyword `this` in my methods with Mongoose, well, it returns me an `undefined` value, while for a `pre` method, I get the asked values.
I'm running with bcrypt-nodejs, and mongoose for this file. I don't think the problem come from the way I call it on the API, because it get to the right way before arriving the method.
Here's the code :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const StaffSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: {type: String, required: true},
    lastname: {type: String, required: true},
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    type: {type: String, required: true},
});

StaffSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    let staff = this;
    console.log(staff);
    if (!staff.isModified('password')) {
        return next();
    }
    bcrypt.hash(staff.password, null, null, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        staff.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});

StaffSchema.methods.comparePasswords = function(password) {
    console.log(password, this.password);
    if(this.password != null) {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Staff', StaffSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the issue.
Never talk too fast, the issue came from the API...
In fact, on the select, I removed the password, so it couldn't find it. Silly mistake, my bad.
I had this before,

```
loginRouter.post('/', (req, res) => {
        Staff.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
        .select('firstname lastname username email type')
```

and now here's the fix :

```
loginRouter.post('/', (req, res) => {
        Staff.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
        .select('firstname lastname username password email type')
```